# rails index.js.erb not loading

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, pagination

I am attempting to do some ajax for pagination but I canno get index.js.erb to load or be recognized in any way. I'm following railscast 240:https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-240/store/app/views/products/_products.html.erb

I am using the code below:

index.js.erb

`$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>");`

The request seems to go through properly, but the HTML isn't loading. Nothing changes (no errors though)

Comment: Gabriel, the quotes are fine. Rails handles the code between <%= and %>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because I had `format |do|` in my controller without format.js. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'products/products')) %>
```

instead of

```
<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>
```